# Why is $\sqrt{\sin^2 x} = |\sin x|$?

Tags: trigonometry

Please thoroughly explain this as I am completely lost. I kind if understand but if $\sin x$ is negative, then $\sin^2 x$ is a positive number and then the square root would be $|\sin x|$for sure but wouldn't it also be $-\sin x$?

Comment: The *function* $x \mapsto \sqrt{x} : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is by definition the (*positive*) square root of $x$. That is, it is the unique real number $y \geq 0$ such that $y^2 = x$. That's why the absolute value is necessary.

Comment: To address the last 6 words of the question: Yes, when $\sin x$ is negative, $|\sin x|=-\sin x$.  And when $\sin x$ is positive, $|\sin x|=\sin x$.  And when $\sin x$ is zero, both of these are true.  The point of the absolute value notation $|\sin x|$ is to incorporate all those cases into one formula.

Comment: For every real number $u$, we have $\sqrt{u^{2}} = |u|$. This fundamental identity is often mis-remembered (and possibly mis-taught).

Comment: Distinguish carefully the phrases "the square root" and "a square root". Every positive number $r$ has two distinct square roots $\pm\sqrt{r}$. They are opposites; by common convention, the positive one (denoted $\sqrt{r}$) is "the" square root and the negative one (the opposite of "the" square root, $-\sqrt{r}$) has no special name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute value is (sometimes) defined as
$$
|x|=\begin{cases} x & \text{if $x\geq 0$}\\
-x & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
So, 
$$
|\sin x|=\begin{cases} \sin x & \text{if $\sin x\geq 0$}\\
-\sin x & \text{if $\sin x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
So, when $\sin x<0$, $|\sin x|$ means $-\sin x$.  But, when $\sin x \geq 0$, $|\sin x|$ means $\sin x$.